# web app deployed on jboss suddenly extremely slow

Tags: performance, jboss, web

I have a Web App deployed on JBoss App Server 7.0.2 on Windows XP

It had been running fine for the past 6 months then suddenly, it is painfully slow when launching in Internet Explorer 7

The Web App uses java, facelets, and hibernate.  Any suggestions how I can begin to locate the problem?  I don't know where I should start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by looking at memory.

Download Visual VM 1.3.3, install all the plugins, and attach it to your JBOSS PID.  It'll show you all generations of the heap, CPU, threads, which objects consume the most memory, etc.

Information and insight are what you need.  Anything without data is merely a guess.

The other question that needs asking: what "suddenly" changed?  I'd start asking about changes on that server: software upgrades, other apps installed, patches, everything.

You should also be looking at dependencies.  What about the database server logs?

Comment: it's not database. same result with app on different dbs. most likely jars included in webapp.  that changed.  But will run vm